# How do I scrape text with no style in HTML?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to scrape a time-stamp value which has no CSS associated to it:

```
<a href="famg.xml">famg.xml</a>              05-Sep-2012 22:21   32M   
<a href="file.203.xml">file.203.xml</a>      12-Apr-2013 21:02   11K   
<a href="file.202.xml">file.202.xml</a>      13-Apr-2013 16:08  1.7K   
<a href="file.201.xml">file.201.xml</a>      14-Apr-2013 16:14  1.8K   
<a href="file.212.xml">file.212.xml</a>      16-Apr-2013 09:02  1.1K
```

If I use `doc.css('a')`, I got all the `<a>` elements, but when I look at the time-stamp value it's outside of `<a>` and has no CSS associated with it.

I want to read each file-name and its time-stamp and make sure if it was generated today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `next_sibling.text` on each `'a'` element you select.

```
doc.css('a').each { |x|
  puts x.next_sibling.text
}
```

Comment: Awesome NevDull !! thanks a lot ...I really appreciate the quick response..it works fine..

Comment: Priti, it doesnt let me in as I dont have 20 reputation point  :( ..sad ah!!?? I am new to Stack Overflow...will improve my reputation and join

Comment: @Krish, since this works for you, you should accept this answer.

Comment: how can i do that Mark ? educate me plz

Comment: You can also do: `puts doc.css('a').map(&:text)`.